# Use of Carousel in TabPanel while using Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs

I want to ask that can one add a Carousel in a TabPanel while developing an app in sencha touch ??
I just want to add a tab named gallery and Put some images in a carousel .. 
Please Help ..

The code is as follows...

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Employee Form',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
            fullscreen: true,
            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },
            layout: {
                animation: {
                    type: 'slide'
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    html: 'You are on the Home Screen Now' + ['<center><img width="100%" height="350px" src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" /></center>'].join(""),
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            html: '<center>Muhammad Burhan</center>',
                            docked: 'bottom',
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Gallery',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'carousel',
                            direction: 'vertical',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    html: 'Welcome' + ['<center><img width="60%" height="100%" src="lib/touch/img/welcome.gif"</center>'].join(),
                                },
                                {
                                    html: 'First Picture' + ['<center><img width="100%" height="100%" src="lib/touch/img/pic.jpg" /></center>'].join(""),
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create the carousel with the image seperately from the Tab panel and just put the carousel as an item with the title Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#DQ0wD

You actually need to make your second tabbar item a carousel and not adding a carousel item to  your tabbar item like you tried to do.

Hope this helped

Comment: TDeBailleul thanks for kind solution. I have got the solution..  Thanx again for ur reply

Comment: You're welcome. Then either accept this answer or post your own answer and accept it.